# проблема с парсером AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, парсер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


zona = input("Введите значение отдела(Запрещённые судом курсы и книги - 971): ")
fov = int(input("Введите число страниц(+1; Например: страниц 40, мы пишем 41): "))
headers = {
    'Host': 'vavilon.cc',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36 OPR/87.0.4390.25',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}

tot = []

for count in range(1, fov):
    
    url = f'https://vavilon.cc/forums/{zona}/page-{count}'

    va_request = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=('ing2123', 'Mixail21212'))
    # print(va_request.status_code)
    va_soup = BeautifulSoup(va_request.text, "lxml")

    av = va_soup.find_all("div", {'class': 'structItem-title'})
    # print(av)
    for i in av:
        title = i.find("a", {'data-xf-init': 'preview-tooltip'})
        titn = "https://vavilon.cc" + title.get("href")
        tit = title.get_text()
        tot.append(
            {
            'Название': tit,
            'Ссылка': titn
            }
            )
with open('va.txt', 'w') as file:
    print(*tot, file=file, sep="\n")    
# print(tot)
```

Выводит:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py\ag\va.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(*tot, file=file, sep="\n")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xd7' in position 42: character maps to <undefined>
```

И иногда:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py\ag\va.py", line 29, in <module>
    titn = "https://vavilon.cc" + title.get("href")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Подскажите как решить проблему с `Traceback (most recent call last)` и как сделать запись в файл не в строку, а в виде:

```
tot.append(
                {
                'Название': tit,
                'Ссылка': titn
                }
                )
```

Comment: ну так добавьте строкой выше проверку вида `if title  is None: continue` и все.

Comment: Попробуйте указать кодировку `utf-8` для записи файла, `cp1251` что-то не справляется. И ещё хорошо бы не `va_request.text` в `BS` передавать, а `va_request.content`

Comment: Нет при, кодировании файла utf-8 в файл ничего не записывается, и va_request.content, ловит кучу ошибок.

Comment: Ясно 'va_request.content' наверное работает, но я положил сайт.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо CrazyElf и KoVadim, теперь всё работает как надо.

```
    va_soup = BeautifulSoup(va_request.content, "lxml")

    av = va_soup.find_all("div", {'class': 'structItem-title'})
    # print(av)
    for i in av:
        title = i.find("a", {'data-xf-init': 'preview-tooltip'})
        if title  is None: continue
        titn = "https://vavilon.cc" + title.get("href")
        tit = title.get_text()
        tot.append(
            {
            'Название': tit,
            'Ссылка': titn
            }
            )
with open('va.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    print(*tot, file=file, sep="\n")
```